# Read a matrix, output all the ​ (i, j)​ pairs where the sum of ith row is equal to jth column

Tags: c, arrays

Read a matrix, output all the ​ (i, j)​ pairs where the sum of ith row is equal to jth column.

**Example:**

**Input :**

```
1   2  14  8
2   4  3   4
15  7  8  -5
```

**Output :**

(1,1), (0,2), (2,2)   // in any order

**Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 50

int main()
{
    int i=0, j=0, r, c; 
    int arr[max][max], sum_r[max], sum_c[max];
    printf("Enter the number of rows(r):");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Enter the number of columns(c):");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]:",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        sum_r[i]=0;
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            sum_r[i] = sum_r[i] + arr[i][j];
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        sum_c[j]=0;
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            sum_c[j] = sum_c[j] + arr[i][j];
        }
        j++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            if(sum_r[i]==sum_c[j]) printf("(%d,%d)",i,j);
        }
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

**My input :**

```
Enter the number of rows(r):3
Enter the number of columns(c):4
a[0][0]:1
a[0][1]:2
a[0][2]:14
a[0][3]:8
a[1][0]:2
a[1][1]:4
a[1][2]:3
a[1][3]:4
a[2][0]:15
a[2][1]:7
a[2][2]:8
a[2][3]:-5
```

**My output :**

(0,2)(1,1)(1,3)(2,2)   //Extra (1,3) why ??

Further this code is not working for other input cases. Can't figure out any mistakes.

Comment: The example input missing the dimension setting part.

Comment: dimension could be any as specified by user

Comment: Please cut-and-paste your actual input and output when you run the code (and add it to the question rather than just the input array you intend to input).

Comment: @Alpha I understand that, but your program expect to set firstly the dimensions which not happens in your example input so its not a complete example. I know you could say it could be inferred by looking at it, but who knows you might just swapped them or something so its needed. Also for reproductability.

Comment: So what changes should i make??

Comment: You use another `i++` and `j++` at the end of the loops, which is wrong. The variables get already incremented once at the end of each iteration.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include another mistake: you have extra `i++` and `j++` statements in your summation loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop to compute `sum_c`, you count `j` only up to `r` instead of to `c`.

EDIT:
You also have too many increments: `i++` and `j++` each occur twice in their respective summation loops. Remove the stand-alone increments inside your `sum_r` and `sum_c` loops.

Comment: Are you saying the extra (wrong) output still occurs after you changed the code? Or that the code in the question is hand typed fresh, not a cut-n-paste of your actual code?

Comment: i checked my algorithm process and figured out a change in for loop condition bit still it gives wrong output

Comment: Do you enter `-5` or `5` as the last entry? Please show the complete example input and output so we can better understand what's happening.